# How do I specify which field I am ordering by?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I have a RQL query that looks like this:

```
r.table('builds')
    .orderBy(r.desc('createdDate'))
    .limit(100)
    .eqJoin('userId', r.table('users'))
    .run(connection)
```

Both `builds` and `users` have a `createdDate` field. I am expecting the results to be sorted by the `createdDate` of the `builds` table, but I'm actually getting them in the order of the `users` table.

How do I specify that I'd like to user the `builds` table's `createdDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is somewhat clearly explained [in the RethinkDb docs](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq_join/). Look for the example involving `without()`

My query ended up looking like this:

```
r.table('builds')
    .eqJoin('userId', r.table('users'))
    .without({right: 'createdDate'})
    .zip()
    .orderBy(r.desc('createdDate'))
    .limit(100)
    .run(connection)
```

The following also seemed to work, but `ordered` is not advised.

```
r.table('builds')
    .orderBy(r.desc('createdDate'))
    .eqJoin('userId', r.table('users'), {ordered: true})
    .limit(100)
    .run(connection)
```

While this works, I don't fully understand. Any additional explanation or answers are fully welcome.

Answer (score 0):

*After* the join, you should have a 'right' object containing your users that you can operate on. Something like:

```
r.table('builds')
 .eqJoin('userId', r.table('users'))
 .orderBy(r.desc('right.createdDate'))
 .limit(100)
 .run(connection)
```

Comment: Can you point me to the right place in the docs where I could have discovered this?